# Protractor Cannot read property 'timeout' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, protractor, gulp-protractor

I have been writing dozens of Protractor tests for my current angular project and they all work.

I pasted tests to create a new set of tests, and noticed that if there is a `describe` nested directly inside another `describe`, I get a `Cannot read property 'timeout' of undefined` error and Protractor exits with code 100.

If I remove the nested `describe`, it works right away.

If there is an `it` before the nested `describe`, that works... so all of it seams extremely strange to me.

Here is the test and the error:

Code:

```
/* eslint max-len: 0 */
/* eslint-env es6 */
'use strict';

var chai = require('chai');
var expect = chai.expect;
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
var config = require('../../../../gulp/config');

chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

describe('Compléter la reception de l\'offre d\'acquisition', function describe() {
  var localhost = config.e2e.localhost;

  this.timeout(15000);

  describe('View mode:', function () {
    it('Should redirect the user to the /tableauoffre page when clicking on "Quitter"', function it() {
      browser.get('/tableauoffre');

      browser.waitForAngular()
        .then(function getFirstRow() {
          return element(by.id('table-0'))
            .all(by.css('tbody tr'))
            .get(0);
        })
        .then(function click(row) {
          return row
            .all(by.css('a'))
            .get(0)
            .click();
        })
        .then(function redirect() {
          return browser.getCurrentUrl();
        })
        .then(function click() {
          return element(by.id('quitter-btn'))
            .click();
        })
        .then(function url() {
          return browser.getCurrentUrl();
        })
        .then(function test(url) {
          expect(url).to.equal(`${localhost}/tableauoffre`);
        });
    });
  });
});
```

Error:

```
[11:21:24] Starting 'protractor'...
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'timeout' of undefined
    at describe (/Users/[user-name]/Documents/banq/trunk/app/modules/views/assigner.offre/assigner.offre.e2e.js:15:7)
    at Suite.describe (/Users/[user-name]/Documents/banq/trunk/app/modules/views/assigner.offre/assigner.offre.e2e.js:21:3)
    at context.describe.context.context (/Users/[user-name]/Documents/banq/trunk/node_modules/mocha/lib/interfaces/bdd.js:47:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/[user-name]/Documents/banq/trunk/app/modules/views/assigner.offre/assigner.offre.e2e.js:12:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
[launcher] Process exited with error code 100

/Users/[user-name]/Documents/banq/trunk/gulp/tasks/protractor.js:24
      throw err;
      ^
Error: protractor exited with code 100
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/[user-name]/Documents/banq/trunk/node_modules/gulp-protractor/index.js:63:27)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
```

Comment: why are you even nesting the the describe any particular reason?

Comment: I am nesting to separate 2 versions of one view: edit and view mode. That said, it is supported to do that, so why shouldn't matter too much unless I was breaking an unwritten rule

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea... Try

```
var self = this;
self.timeout(15000);
```

I don't understand you problem either, but I just would give that a try. Anyway, it is a good trick to store `this` into a variable, at least when you are going to use it further.

What's the purpose of your timeout?

Comment: It does not work, as the error says `timeout` isn't on `this`, so it won't be on `self` either... If I don't user the timeout, my tests will randomly fail because they timeout, even if I increase the timeout in my config file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I found out that naming you callback functions and using a function named the same inside of its scope actually confuses things, hence why `this` didn't have the right properties on it.

So, always call you callback functions using a unique name.

Comment: Could you also please to provide the code example?